# tensorflow-gpu running failure on LINUX

Tags: tensorflow

I've installed CUDA and cuDnn on ubuntu 16.04.

CUDA version : 9.0 // with driver version 390.87

cuDNN version : 7.2 for CUDA9.0

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

works fine, but

```
tf.Session()
```

renders the following error.

```
2018-09-15 16:43:23.281375: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1484] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-09-15 16:43:23.281431: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:158] Internal: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/home/imhgchoi/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1494, in __init__
super(Session, self).__init__(target, graph, config=config)
 File "/home/imhgchoi/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 626, in __init__
self._session = tf_session.TF_NewSession(self._graph._c_graph, opts)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed to create session.
```

The error message implies that I've installed the wrong version of CUDA driver, but I'm lost. I'm not sure what steps to take in order to remedy this situation.

---

AFTER ADDING ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES

That only added new errors..

```
2018-09-15 17:13:39.684390: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2018-09-15 17:13:39.767963: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:897] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2018-09-15 17:13:39.768481: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1405] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.506
pciBusID: 0000:09:00.0
totalMemory: 3.94GiB freeMemory: 3.41GiB
2018-09-15 17:13:39.768502: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1484] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-09-15 17:13:39.768635: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:158] Internal: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it is your envirnment variables causing this problem.
try this:

Add these lines at the end of your ~/.bashrc file and open a terminal and simply start a python session there and then import tensorflow (you should have the tensporflow-gpu installed via apt) and see if it works:

```
sudo vim ~/.bashrc
```

and add these at the end of the file and restart your terminal:

```
export CUDA_HOME="/usr/local/cuda-9.0"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${CUDA_HOME}/lib64"
export PATH="${CUDA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="${CUDA_HOME}/lib"
```

Edit.1

Please make sure that "usr/local/cuda-9.0" is the directory that you installed cuda.

Comment: That added errors.. :( I've updated the errors on my post

Comment: What does nvcc --version return in ur terminal? @HyeongGyuFroilanChoi